# Nest templates with structs

Tags: c++

```
template<int N, typename operation, typename T>
 struct cascade{
  operation op;
   struct cascade<N-1, operation, T> next;
  T operator()(T t){return(op(next(t)))};
  cascade(operation* ops):op(ops[N-1]),next(ops)

 }

cascade<3, biquad<float>, float> filter(cascade_elements);
```

For the above code, when an instance of the cascade struct is created, an op variable holding an object biquad is created
Is next an instance of the struct cascade again?

```
struct cascade<N-1, operation, T> next
```

If so, it would call the constructor of struct again but with no arguments. 
What im confused about is what is done first?
Is the instance of the embedded struct created before the initilisation of the 1st constructor call:

```
cascade(operation* ops):op(ops[N-1]),next(ops)
```

If so, the embedded instance will call another constructor before the first constructor finishes initialising the embedded struct instance

Comment: Do you have a base case for `cascade`? From the looks of it, `cascade` will recurse indefinitely. Please provide a true [mcve]

Comment: I cannot sorry, these are just some notes from my lecture. Lecturer hasn't provided anything but this, hes not very good tbh

Answer (score 0):

> For the above code, when an instance of the cascade struct is created, an op variable holding an object biquad is created Is next an instance of the struct cascade again?

Sort of. Please remember that `cascade` is not a `struct`. It is a `struct` template. A containg `struct` is not the same type as the type of `next`. When you create an instance of `cascade<10, SomeOp, SomeType>`, it holds an instance of `cascade<9, SomeOp, SomeType>`, which holds an instance of `cascade<8, SomeOp, SomeType>`, etc. As you can see, this will a problem without a terminating type in the recursion. A terminating type can be something like:

```
template<typename operation, typename T>
struct cascade<0, operation, T>
{
   ...
};
```

that does not have a `next` in it.

> If so, it would call the constructor of struct again but with no arguments.

No, it won't. `next` is a different type. You are explitly initializing it in the constructor with `op`.

> What im confused about is what is done first?

Now that you know they are two different type, I hope it is not confusing any longer.

> Is the instance of the embedded struct created before the initilisation of the 1st constructor call:
>
> ```
> cascade(operation* ops):op(ops[N-1]),next(ops)
> ```

Once again, I hope this is not confusing any longer.

---

Here's a simpler version of your class, with a `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N, typename T>
struct cascade 
{
   struct cascade<N-1, T> next;

   cascade() : next()
   {
      std::cout << "Constructing an object with template parameter " << N << std::endl;
   }
};

template<typename T>
struct cascade<0, T>
{
   cascade()
   {
      std::cout << "Constructing an object with template parameter " << 0 << std::endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   cascade<10, int> c;
}
```

And its output:

```
Constructing an object with template parameter 0
Constructing an object with template parameter 1
Constructing an object with template parameter 2
Constructing an object with template parameter 3
Constructing an object with template parameter 4
Constructing an object with template parameter 5
Constructing an object with template parameter 6
Constructing an object with template parameter 7
Constructing an object with template parameter 8
Constructing an object with template parameter 9
Constructing an object with template parameter 10
```

Hopefully the explanation in the first part of the answer makes more sense now.

Comment: I still do not quite understand, struct cascade<N-1, operation, T> next;
cascade<N-1, operation, T> next;

Doesnt the 2nd statement hold an instance? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @LuckyFughck, I updated the answer with an example program. Hopefully that makes thing a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you, i have one last question. Is the constructor called before any member variables are created? Or both at the same time?

Comment: What is the purpose of struct cascade<N-1, operation, T> next;?
cascade<N-1, operation, T> next;  works too...

Comment: @LuckyFughck, the answer to the first question is something you should learn from a textbook. The order of initializationi of sub-objects and member variables  of classes is very clearly defined. It does not make sense for me to repeat that in a comment.

Comment: @LuckyFughck, the `struct` part is superfluous. You can, and should, leave it out.

Comment: One more question, what is the purpose of cascade() : next()?
cascade() will also work too...
An instance is created for every instance of the struct, for every instance a constructor is called. Is it only neccessary for passing in parameters to the instance through the constructor? If so.. the constructor must be called first?

Comment: Could you please upvote the question so i dont get banned please @R Sahu
Also thank you for your help!

Comment: @LuckyFughck, I don't think you are at risk for getting banned. It will be useful to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through the section on [ask].